# what should I do if I got a null pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

The main thing is I don't know the best practice of handling null pointers.

here is the code:

```
int GetSomeVal()
{
    if(ptr)
    {
        return *ptr
    }
    else
    {
        // What here?
        // Should I return 0? or -1 or throw an exception?
    }
}
```

I got this question because in google's c++ style-guide, it doesn't recommand us to use exceptions, and this may be another topic.

If I should use exceptions, does that mean I have to design an exception class an throw it?
If I should not use exceptions, what is the best practice?

Comment: What is the semantic meaning of `ptr` being NULL? Is it normal? Does it mean that something horrible happened? Is it so bad that your program can't continue executing? How you handle it depends on what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it makes sense for `ptr` to be `NULL`, you shouldn't throw an exception. Exceptions are used to indicate something went wrong.

If `ptr` is `NULL` because something went wrong, by all means, throw an exception.

Google's code style is to be used by Google. They prohibit lots of things (like reference arguments, exceptions, etc.) that are normally used in any high-level OO language. You shouldn't obey it unless you work for Google.

You could design your own exception class, derive it from `std::exception`, and throw that from the code.

Also, from your code, `ptr` is a member. If it was supposed to get initialized in the constructor and it didn't, perhaps you should throw the exception from the constructor. There's no use in having an un-usable object.

Comment: Even google admits that those rules are not generally usable.

Comment: Man, they're even scared of using `unsigned int`s for unsigned numbers ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use these options in this order in case you don't want to throw exceptions

1. `boost::optional`
2. `int GetSomeVal(int &ok)` - make ok `false` if pointer is `NULL`
3. return some error code if pointer is `NULL` (`-1` for example)

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on the function specification.

`ptr==NULL` may be a valid but exceptional input to the function, for example, it was caused by incorrect input data to the program. Then the best way to handle it is to return an error code or throw an exception which is intended to be handled up the call chain.

In other cases, `ptr==NULL` could never happen by design, but only because of a bug elsewhere. Then the best way is to log the error and terminate the program.

Comment: +1: the proper handling of null pointer arguments is part of designing the interface to a function, and cannot be determined from looking at the code.